# Popup blocker getting triggered cause of setTimeout in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, settimeout

I have a scenario where on Button click I need to open a URL in a new tab after a 300 ms delay

The issue is that I am using settimeout and because of that the browser assumes the window.open is not triggered because of user interaction and shows a pop up message instead of opening the URL.

Is there anyway I can opgen the URL on Button click with a delay without causing the pop up blocker to fire?

TIA

Btn.addEventListner('click', function (){setTimeout( function(){  window.open(url,'_blank'),300)}

Apologies for the bad formatting. I am typing from my phone

Comment: I just tested this in IE 11 and it opened the new tab without a popup alert. There may be something else (like an add-on in your browser) that is causing the behavior you are observing

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the response.  Which version of ie are you using ? I believe the pop up blocker is displayed when the pop up is triggered without user interaction(in my case the settimeout callback).
But this issue is not just on my PC , it is reported by a lot of my clients.

Comment: I've made a test on my side and it works well without a popup blocker on IE9-11. IE8 and older could not work because "Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'". Could you please share your detailed code so that it will be easier to reproduce your problem and solve it.